Нужно ли многоточие в последней цитате(перед и)?
...назвал работу Ефима Фомича «машинным производством», «рефлекторным правописанием», которое «и гроша не стоит».

Можно написать так: ...назвал работу Ефима Фомича «машинным производством» и «рефлекторным правописанием», которое «и гроша не стоит».
Пояснение
В предложении можно использовать свободное комбинирование цитат, например:
Собственно, первый митинг у памятника Пушкину и состоялся в день его открытия. По воспоминаниям современников, вся площадь была заполнена людьми, охваченными восторгом, в момент снятия с монумента холстины толпа прокричала «ура». Юрист Анатолий Кони назвал это событие «блестящим проявлением оживления» после «затхлой атмосферы застоя», а поэт Иван Аксаков — «радостным благовестом нашего мужающего, наконец, самосознания».
